# How to tell a makefile that a file has not been updated

Tags: makefile

I would like to force a makefile to ignore some files updates. Is it possible ?

I copy sources from another repository before building, so the sources are newer than the build target but most of the time they are identical.

Comment: Why not create a `make` rule that copies a source file from the other repository *if and only if* that source has been updated?  As it stands it sounds like you're deliberately trying to subvert `make`.

Comment: If I copy only the updated sources, it will be missing some sources to build the target.

Comment: But the idea is that if a file is missing from the local repository it will be considered out of date (or updated) and copied from the other repository.  Is the remote repository under source control such as `git`?  If so it sounds as if a simple rule invoking `git pull` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: *"I copy sources from another repository before building..._* How? Why? As @G.M. says, that seems like the right place to put the discrimination. You *can* do it afterward, but at the cost of an uglier makefile.

Comment: I agree that the process you're using sounds like it's not going to be robust.  However, to answer your question you can use make's `-o` option to tell make that a file is old, regardless of its timestamp.  Note, you'll have to pass this option for each file every time you invoke make.

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist, the -o option seems to answer to my needs.
For the others, sorry but it's too long to describe my compilation architecture and why I have chosen this one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you use `rsync` to update the files, it will not change the timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your exact needs, but one solution might be this:

```
    cp --preserve=timestamps repository/$file $file
```

This will cause the copied file to have the same timestamp as the one in the repository, so it will only be considered new if the repository is newer than your workspace (which can be a good thing, as if you update your repository, then make will know to rebuild what's needed).

Alternatively, if your repository is say a git repository, you could do:

```
force_download_%:
       date=$$(git log -1 --format=%i $*) && \
         git co -f $$file && \
         touch -d "$$date" $$file;

do_downloads: force_download_foo.c force_download_bar.c
.PHONY: force_download_foo.c force_download_bar.c
```

Which would set the date to the time the files were submitted into the repository.   Again, if the repository is updated, make will know to rebuild any files dependent on the newly checked out file.